# log4j not zipping log files

Tags: java, logging

I am not able to understand what I am missing here. Below is my log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.home}/logs/broker.log 
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/logs/broker-.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to set `MaxFileSize`,just add the following to your RollingFileAppender configuration and having the filename end in .gz will automagically compress your logfiles:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy 
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.home}/logs/broker.log 
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/logs/broker-.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10M
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

hope that helped